# Testing React with Jasmine - React.addons.TestUtitilies - 404s on all but React Tests

Tags: testing, jasmine

I'm adding React to an existing codebase in Rails, using the react-rails gem. I was in the middle of finishing up my Jasmine tests, when I uncovered an issue with testing click events in my React components. I started by using a regular old jQuery .trigger(). I learned here that this does not play well with the React component at all and does not fire the event React is waiting for.

Doing some research, I discovered the React Test Utilities addon. After turning it on in config/application.rb, I tested and found the addon to be available *outside of the Jasmine suite*. All of my javascript files are not loading with Jasmine and returning as 404s.

In config/applcation.rb I've added the line:

```
module ReactTesting
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.react.addons = true
  end
end
```

I find this odd, that all my other Jasmine tests are no longer loading. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple: Moved the ReactTesting module to the bottom of application.rb. Solved all my problems.